# Modpython and virtualenv

Tags: python, django, mod-python, virtualenv

Is it any way to run django site on virtualenv without administration rights? How can I do it? Virtualenv is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but [not with mod_python](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments).

Comment: Does it make any diferrence with working Django applications writed on mod_python?  
And, need I administrator righst to install mod_wsgi?

Comment: Not really, and yes, respectively.

Comment: So, how can I run my Django website on virtualenv and mod_wsgi without administration rights? Virtualenv and mod_wsgi are installed, but I've got no access to apache config files.

Comment: It seems as though the truly important mod_wsgi directives do require access to the server config files.

Comment: It can be done with mod_wsgi from .htaccess if you are allowed FileInfo override. Read 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines' to start with. Specifically look at AddHandler method for configuring mod_wsgi.